# Describing an entire system using Design Patterns?

Tags: actionscript-3, oop, design-patterns

for my master thesis I am making a system for federating knowledge in as3. It is much like SpicyNodes or similar software, but with more advanced functionality. My mentor has now adviced me to describe the system using Design Patterns. However, my knowledge about the subject is slim to none. I have just read the book Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software.

My problem is how do I go about describing the system using the patterns? Do I use one UML diagram? Do I go through the system class for class, describing them using design patterns? The client is not large, nor very advanced. Less than 20 classes in addition to a server side php script.

Any hints how I should go about doing this task is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is an example of something like what you want that was done with junit after the fact: [JUnit A Cook's Tour](http://junit.sourceforge.net/doc/cookstour/cookstour.htm). also, i am not sure that your language has full support for inheritance and polymorphism. if it does not, then these (inheritance and polymorphism) would be considered to be design patterns.

Comment: A rather small example, but seems like I have to do something similar. I guess I will have to cook up an UML diagram and show it to my mentor to see what he says about it. Thanks =)